# Using JQuery append on android using phonegap

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

I'm trying to use JQuery's append method on an android application using phonegap, however it does not seem to work, and in fact causes the page to fail loading.
commenting out the append call fixes that...
(The page loads just fine when opened in Chrome)

Is this a phonegap or android bug or what?
Is there a workaround to get append to work or something similar to append that works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The PhoneGap Demo with jQuery Mobile demo at [this demos page](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/included-demo-apps) successfully uses jQuery append [here](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/source/browse/tags/r1.2/com.mds.apg/resources/jqm/phonegapExample/main.js).

If this isn't enough to help, you'll likely need to show the specific code that is not working.